# Как найти и отредактировать нужный бизнес-процесс в Битрикс?

Tags: битрикс

Осваиваю Битрикс.
Структура процесса: 
- приходит электронная завка на подразделение;
- сотрудник его принимает заявку и формирует задачу на какого-то исполнителя.
Нужно сделать так, чтобы при формировании задачи на конкретного исполнителя (назовем его id=1234), конечная дата выполнения задачи (а также и заявки) увеличивалась бы на 1 день.
Извините, если путаюсь в терминах.

Comment: [Хелпдеск](https://helpdesk.bitrix24.ru/open/6603593/) и [документация](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=57) Вам в помощь

Comment: Спасибо, полезная информация. А как-то быстро проблему можно решить?

Comment: Перешел по первой ссылке. "Перейдите в пункт Бизнес-процессы левого меню. Именно отсюда выполняются все настройки, а также здесь можете увидеть всю историю по прошлым и текущим бизнес-процессам. " Захожу в Бизнес-процессы и не вижу ни одного. Это значит, что моя задача не касается бизнес-процессов?

Comment: С какой тогда стороны подойти к ее решению?

Comment: По-прежнему нужна помощь! Есть специалисты?

Comment: Если нет, значит вы должны создать новый Бизнес-процесс с тем функционалом который Вам нужен.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас двигаюсь в этом направлении. Но этот же ж как-то работает. Нужно внести сюда коррективы.

Comment: Тогда тут вопрос есть ли у Вас доступ к данному процессу. Запросите ссылку на данный процесс. Запросите права администратора.